# MySql - How to store stored function in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to define a ruleset how I priorize my results.

I'd like to create a table like

```
+--------------------------------+------------+  
|       operation_to_do          | multiplier |
+================================+============+  
|  function(){return age+birth}  |      5     |
+--------------------------------+------------+ 
| function(){return  footsize*2} |      8     |
+--------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: What have you tried? More importantly, why are you doing this?

Comment: You don't.  That is not how SQL works.

Comment: I didn't try anything, because i have no idea where to start. 
The rules I have to order by results can changing. If I store it as a number in the table when the customer change the rules, find out a new one or think that one is more important than the other, i have to update my table. If I calculate it in query, the business logic would be invisible

Comment: I open to any hacked, smelly solutions, too...

Answer (score 1):

You can store any text you wish in a column of a table, including bits and pieces of programs, like the (apparently) Javascript functions in your example. But SQL does not attempt to run such programs automatically in any way. You need to retrieve those text values (using SELECT queries) and then cause them to be run from your program (nodejs?). That is possible, but requires careful programming.

If you want weighting functions in your SQL queries, they need to appear in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
   SELECT *
     FROM your_data
    ORDER BY (  (8 * (footsize*2)) + (5 * (age+birth))
```

might do the trick for you.